# How can i fix warning that Class 'Shape' is exposed outside its defined visibility scope? (JAVA 17)

Tags: java, function, enums, warnings, visibility

I made function 'warn' in line 17 whose parameter is enum Shape.
Why warning about visibility scope and how can I fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaCalculator {

    enum Shape {TRIANGLE, RECTANGLE, CIRCLE}
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = scanner.next();

        while (!str.equals("quit")){
            str = str.toUpperCase();
            warn(Shape.valueOf(str));
        }
    }

    public static void warn(Shape shape) { //warning

    }
```

Intellij recommend generate overloaded method with default parameter values like following code.

```
public static void warn(){
    warn(null);
}
```

But I think it doesn't look intuitive.

Comment: Make `enum Shape` `public`, or `warn` not `public`.

Comment: Make `Shape` public, or make `warn` package-private (or private).

Comment: You've learned something important, when a static analysis tool like IntelliJ (or SonarQube) suggests something, it might remove the warning, but in a really stupid way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why is there a warning `Class 'Shape' is exposed outside its defined visibility scope`?

Because the `enum` `AreaCalculator.Shape` is only visible to classes in the same package, but the method `public static void warn(Shape shape)` is visible to any class.

So if we write a class:

```
package a;

import b.AreaCalculator;

public class AreaCalculatorClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AreaCalculator.warn(AreaCalculator.Shape.CIRCLE);
    }
}
```

It will fail to compile, because `'b.AreaCalculator.Shape' is not public in 'b.AreaCalculator'. Cannot be accessed from outside package`.

The fix is to with make `Shape` public or `warn` package-private, depending on your intent.

The fix suggested by IntelliJ IDEA is something you might do if you're convinced that you've chosen the correct visibility for `Shape`, and yet you want to call something like the `warn` method from arbitrary classes.

Comment: I love your answer! thank u :)

Comment: @hong: there's a dedicated button meaing "love this answer", which is the upvote button, you should probably press that (in fact that's preferable to posting it as a comment). Additionally, if it helped to solve your problem, feel free to accept the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I made function 'warn' in line 17 whose parameter is enum Shape. Why warning about visibility scope and how can I fix it? ..."*

I'm not receiving any warning here, the code compiles.
If I enter any of the values I get an infinite loop.

To resolve this, assign *str* upon each *while-loop* iteration.

```java
String str;

while (!(str = scanner.nextLine()).equals("quit")){
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    warn(Shape.valueOf(str));
}
```

Output

```
TRIANGLE
TRIANGLE
RECTANGLE
RECTANGLE
CIRCLE
CIRCLE
quit
```